# How to use firebase cloud messaging (FCM) with Angular 15?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an angular 15 project, and I want to add FCM to it.

[image]

1. I installed the @angular/fire package..
2. Imported it in app.module like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getMessaging, provideMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() =>
      initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyDsH-k0rqpA19L1kzVG5tBxPjIIdZOaE1A',
        authDomain: 'labifysystem.firebaseapp.com',
        projectId: 'labifysystem',
        storageBucket: 'labifysystem.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '648676237340',
        appId: '1:648676237340:web:61d9762eddc4291c0c3fd9',
        measurementId: 'G-43TJCGGH4H',
      })
    ),
    provideMessaging(() => getMessaging()),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How to request permission and get fcm token in @angular/fire version ^7.5.0??

I found many tutorials and articles that uses this syntax, but it's not a valid syntax in version 7 it's working in @angular/fire version 6.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'fcm-angular-demo';
  message$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private messaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    // Request permission to receive notifications
    this.messaging.requestPermission.subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log('Permission granted');
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Permission denied', error);
      }
    );

    // Get the current FCM token
    this.messaging.getToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
        console.log('Token', token);
        // You can send this token to your server and store it there
        // You can also use this token to subscribe to topics
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Token error', error);
      }
    );

    // Listen for messages from FCM
    this.message$ = this.messaging.messages;
    this.message$.subscribe(
      (message) => {
        console.log('Message', message);
        // You can display the message or do something else with it
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Message error', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to dealing with the lack of documentation on the newer version of @angular/fire is remembering this:

The new version is all about modularity and trying to make it easier to include only what you want and need in your bundle.  So instead of `getToken` belonging to an instance of the service you are injecting, you import the `getToken` **function**, if you need it, and your injected service doesn't come with all possible methods you may or may not need.  This is the case not with just messaging, but `Firestore`, `Storage`, etc.

For example:

```js
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Messaging, getToken, onMessage } from '@angular/fire/messaging';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly _messaging = inject(Messaging);
  private readonly _message = new BehaviorSubject<unknown | undefined>(undefined);

  title = 'fcm-angular-demo';
  message$ = this._message.asObservable();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Request permission to receive notifications
    Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
      if (permission === 'granted') 
        console.log('Permission granted');
      else if (permission === 'denied')
        console.log('Permission denied');
    });

    // Get the current FCM token
    getToken(this._messaging)
      .then((token) => {
        console.log('Token', token);
        // You can send this token to your server and store it there
        // You can also use this token to subscribe to topics
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log('Token error', error));

    // Listen for messages from FCM
    onMessage(this._message, {
      next: (payload) => {
        console.log('Message', payload);
        // You can display the message or do something else with it
      },
      error: (error) => console.log('Message error', error),
      complete: () => console.log('Done listening to messages')
    );
  }
}
```

I'm bummed that the documentation for Angular Fire is still lacking for the latest version in some aspects.  But you'll start to notice a pattern of what they went for, and it is influenced by the non-angular web library becoming more modular.  So if you can't find it in the Angular Fire documentation, head on over to their modular web documentation and most of that documentation applies.  Here is where you can read more on Messaging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to do it as you mentioned but I got an error on the console 
`ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
    at getApp (index.esm2017.js:479:29)
    at getMessagingInWindow (index.esm2017.js:1159:43)
    at angular-fire.js:227:48
    at angular-fire.js:160:59
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:24109:28)
    at runOutsideAngular (angular-fire.js:160:35)`

Comment: did you setup Angular Fire the way they mention to in the README here? https://github.com/angular/angularfire  You need to initialize your app.  I would start with `ng add @angular/fire` and follow the instructions there.  Since you are using Angular 15, I'm assuming your app is not a standalone app, so this command should work.  But if you are using a standalone app, I have an article outlining how to do this.

https://medium.com/@jakehockey10/adding-firebase-to-a-standalone-angular-app-5383aeb2a2ce

Comment: can you please share what your app.module.ts or app.config.ts file looks like?

Comment: they have some sample applications to get you started as well: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/tree/master/samples/advanced

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled it using ng add and it works now, but I got anothor error: `Token error FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:4200/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).`

Comment: I think you need to create that file.  I'd take a look at those links I sent in the previous comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JakeSmith, I created the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file and its working now.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's ok to pass the registration of the Angular service worker (ngsw-worker.js) in the cases when I have it?